# Least Square with homogeneous solution!

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra

I've read somewhere that:

**$x=A^+b+(I-A^+A)Z$** is a solution for $Ax=b$ ,when is doesn't have a particular solution.

where $A^+$ indicates the pseudo-inverse and **$Z$** is an arbitrary vector!!!

I know The first term represents the least square solution but the second term is said to be can used for optimizing secondary criteria and is called the "homogeneous solution". **What is homogeneous solution?** Where does it come from?

Comment: Can you give a reference and maybe some context?

Comment: Page 2 of http://ijr.sagepub.com/content/6/2/72.short

Comment: A has more columns than rows $(m < n)$ and has rank $m$.

Comment: [Singular value decomposition proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209379/singular-value-decomposition-proof/2211001#2211001)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Linear system**

Given the matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}_{\rho}$, and data vector $b\in\mathbb{C}^{m}$, the linear system
$$
\mathbf{A} x = b
$$ 
will have a least squares solution provide that $b\notin\color{red}{\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{A}^{*}\right)}$.

**Least squares solution**
The least squares solution is defined as
$$
  x_{LS} = \left\{
 x \in \mathbb{C}^{n} \colon 
\lVert
  \mathbf{A} x - b
\rVert_{2}^{2}
\text{ is minimized}
\right\}
\tag{1}
$$

As you noted, the least squares solution can be written as
$$
 x_{LS} = \color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{+} b} + 
\color{red}{\left( 
\mathbf{I}_{n} - \mathbf{A}^{+} \mathbf{A}
\right) y}, \quad y\in\mathbb{C}^{n} 
\tag{2}
$$

**Fundamental projector**

The right hand component is the fundamental projector onto the $\color{red}{null}$ space $\color{red}{\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{A}\right)}$
$$
\mathbf{P}_{\color{red}{\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{A}\right)}}
=
\color{red}{\left( 
\mathbf{I}_{n} - \mathbf{A}^{+} \mathbf{A}
\right)}
$$
The least squares solution is the affine space represented by the $\color{red}{red}$, dashed lined. The projector projects vectors onto this $\color{red}{null}$ space. (Note the solution of minimum norm is $\color{blue}{x_{+}} = \color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{+}b}$.)

[image: Row space]

**Full column rank**

When the matrix $\mathbb{A}$ has full column rank, $\rho = n$,

1. the null space $\color{red}{\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A} \right)} = \mathbf{0}$
2. $\mathbf{P}_{\color{red}{\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{A}\right)}}
   \color{red}{\left( 
   \mathbf{I}_{n} - \mathbf{A}^{+} \mathbf{A}
   \right)} = 
    \left( 
   \mathbf{I}_{n} - \mathbf{I}_{n}
   \right) = \mathbf{0}$
3. least squares solution is the point
   $
     \color{blue}{x_{+}} = \color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{+}b},
   $

This is the point in the range space $\color{blue}{\mathcal{R}\left(\mathbf{A}^{*}\right)}$

**Read more**

A bit more background is in [Singular value decomposition proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209379/singular-value-decomposition-proof/2211001#2211001).

---

**Toy problem**

$$
\begin{align}
%
\mathbf{A} x &= b \\
%
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{array} \right]
%
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  x_{1} \\ x_{2}
\end{array} \right]
%
&=
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  b_{1} \\ b_{2}
\end{array} \right]
\end{align}
$$
If $b_{1}\ne0$, the least squares solution exists. Another way to state this condition is
$$
 b\notin\color{red}{\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A}^{*}\right)}
$$

For $b_{2}\ne0$, the general least squares solution can be written as
$$
  x_{LS} = 
\color{blue}{\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  b_{1} \\ 0
\end{array} \right]}
+ \alpha
\color{red}{\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  0 \\ 1
\end{array} \right]}, \quad \alpha \in \mathbb{C}
$$
The fundamental projector onto the null space $\color{red}{\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{A}\right)}$ is 
$$
\mathbf{P}_{\color{red}{\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{A}\right)}}
=
\color{red}{\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{array} \right]}
$$
When $b_{2}=0$, the data vector $b$ is in the $\color{blue}{range}$ space $\color{blue}{\mathcal{R}\left(\mathbf{A}\right)}$, and there is a direct solution
$$
  x = \color{blue}{x_{LS}} = 
\color{blue}{\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  b_{1} \\ 0 
\end{array} \right]}
$$
The direct solution is the least squares solution which is a point in the range space.

Answer (score 2):

The general solution to the homogeneous system of linear equations $Ax=0$ is given by $(I-A^+A)Z$. Hence the name.

Comment: How come $Z$ can be an arbitrary vector?

Comment: I can't find this in my linear algebra books!

Comment: @User1986 One defining property of Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse is that $AA^+A=A$. Now, if $x=(I-A^+A)Z$, then $Ax=(A-AA^+A)Z=(A-A)Z=0$, regardless of the exact value of $Z$.