# Singular value decomposition proof

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, least-squares, svd

I need help in the following question. I'm not sure how to even begin to answer this. What is a possible proof for the following question?

If $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix and $b$ is an $m$-vector, prove that the solution $x$ of minimum Euclidean norm to the least-squares problem $A\cong B$ is given by 
$$x=\sum_{\sigma_i \neq 0} \frac{u_i^Tb}{\sigma_i}v_i$$
where the $\sigma_i$, $u_i$, and $v_i$ are the singular values and corresponding singular vectors of A.

Comment: It would be nice to have the objective function. I have no idea what $\rm A \cong B$ means.

Comment: The least squares solution you post is derived here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772039/how-does-the-svd-solve-the-least-squares-problem/2173715#2173715

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the SVD solve the least squares problem?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772039/how-does-the-svd-solve-the-least-squares-problem)

Comment: I reported this as unclear what you're asking, but at second look it simply appears to be a malicious edit of a valid question. That is to say, a pseudo-deletion.

Comment: Steve, care to explain why you undo edits by others? It's not like you own this post! Did you not read [the fine print](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/licensing)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preliminaries**

Start with a tighter specification on the target matrix:
$$
  \mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}_{\rho}
$$
where the rank $\rho  < \min (m,n)$. The matrix is rank defective and both null spaces are nontrivial.

We are given the data vector $b\notin\color{red}{\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}$ to insure a least squares solution exists. Defining the vector of residual errors
$$
r(x) = \mathbf{A} x - b,
$$
the desire is to find the solution vector $x$ which minimizes the total error $r^{2}$. The solution set is given by the minimizers
$$
  x_{LS} = 
\left\{
  x\in\mathbb{C}^{n} \colon
\lVert
  \mathbf{A} x - b
\rVert_{2}^{2}
\text{ is minimized}
\right\}
$$
For each element in this set, $r^{2}\left(x_{LS}\right)$ achieves minimum value. We are searching for the element in this set which has minimum length.

In [Laub's](http://bookstore.siam.org/ot91/) book (p. 66), he shows the solution is in general an affine space:
[image: Laub excerpt]

represented as the dashed red line in the figure below.

[image: a dagger b]

The singular value decomposition is
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} &=
  \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*} \\
%
 &=
% U 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \mathbf{S}_{\rho\times \rho} & \mathbf{0} \\
     \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
% V 
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
     \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array} \right]  \\
%
\end{align}
$$
The Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse is constructed from the SVD:
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} &=
  \mathbf{V} \, \Sigma^{\dagger} \, \mathbf{U}^{*} \\
%
 &=
% U 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}} & 
     \color{red} {\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \mathbf{S}^{-1} & \mathbf{0} \\
     \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
% V 
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
     \color{red} {\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array} \right]  \\
%
\end{align}
$$
The object of the proof is to show that the pseudoinverse solution has minimum length.

**Trick**

Cast the total error in terms of the SVD and perform a unitary transformation
$$
  r^{2}(x) = 
\lVert
  \mathbf{A} x - b\rVert_{2}^{2}
= 
\lVert
  \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*} x - b
\rVert_{2}^{2}
= 
\lVert
  \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*} x - \mathbf{U}^{*} b
\rVert_{2}^{2}
$$
to separate the $\color{blue}{range}$ and $\color{red}{null}$ spaces.
$$
\begin{align}
  r^{2}(x) = 
\lVert
  \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*} x - \mathbf{U}^{*} b
\rVert_{2}^{2}
&=
\Bigg\lVert
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 \mathbf{S} & \mathbf{0} \\
 \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} \\
\end{array}
\right]
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
     \color{red} {\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array} \right] 
x
-
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
     \color{red} {\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array} \right]  
b
\Bigg\rVert_{2}^{2} \\
%
&=
\big\lVert
\mathbf{S} \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} x - 
  \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} b
-
\color{red} {\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*} b
\big\rVert_{2}^{2} \\
%
&=
\big\lVert
\mathbf{S} \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} x - 
  \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} b
\big\rVert_{2}^{2} + \big\lVert
\color{red} {\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*} b
\big\rVert_{2}^{2} \\
%
\end{align}
$$
How to minimize the total error now? We control the range space component, and we force that contribution to $0$:
$$
r^{2}(x) =
\underbrace{\big\lVert
\mathbf{S} \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} x - 
  \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} b
\big\rVert_{2}^{2}}_{\text{controlled}} + 
\underbrace{\big\lVert
\color{red} {\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*} b
\big\rVert_{2}^{2}}_{\text{uncontrolled}} \\
$$
That is, force
$$
 \mathbf{S} \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} x - 
  \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} b = 0
$$
by setting
$$
  \color{blue}{x_{LS}} = \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}\mathbf{S}^{-1}\color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} b = \color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{\dagger} b}.
$$
The least value for the sums of the squares of residuals is
$$
  r^{2}\left( x_{LS} \right) = \big\lVert
\color{red} {\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*} b
\big\rVert_{2}^{2}
$$
The derivation deliberately avoided the requirement that $\mathbf{A}$ be of full column rank. When the null space $\color{red}{\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}$ is nontrivial, the least squares solution includes a projection onto that null space. The least squares solution set is
$$
  x_{LS} = 
\color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{\dagger}b} +
\color{red} {\left( \mathbf{I}_{n} - \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} \mathbf{A} \right)y},
\quad y\in\mathbb{C}^{n}
$$
Refer back to the blue vector and red dashed line in the previous figure.

*What are the lengths of the least squares solution vectors?*

$$
\lVert
  x_{LS}
\rVert_{2}^{2}
=
\lVert
\color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{\dagger}b} 
\rVert_{2}^{2}
+
\lVert
\color{red} {\left( \mathbf{I}_{n} - \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} \mathbf{A} \right)y}\rVert_{2}^{2}
$$

*What the least squares solution of minimum length?*

It is the vector which is entirely in $\color{blue}{\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}$. It is the pseudoinverse solution.

$$
\lVert
  \color{blue}{x_{LS}}
\rVert_{2}^{2}
=
\lVert
\color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{\dagger}b} 
\rVert_{2}^{2}
$$

Comment: Why is it possible to separate controlled and uncontrolled parts in the 2-norm?

Comment: @errorist: Excuse the sloppy vernacular. The theorem of Pythagorus is used to separate range spaces (blue) from null spaces (red). The range space portion contains the $x$ term which we vary in order to find the best result.  We can adjust $x$ to eliminate the range space contribution to the error. Colloquially, we say "we can control the range space contribution" because of the freedom to choose $x$. There are no such variable parameters in the null space term. The residual error term, $r^{2}(x)$ is a function of $x$ which highlights the role of $x$ in reducing the total error.